# Alphabetical TOC or index for included PDFs

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, pdfpages

I'm putting together a book of fiddle/mandolin tunes. Each tune has some explanatory text followed by the actual music, prepared in an external music engraving program and exported as a PDF. The PDFs are inserted using the 'pdfpages' package with the standard \includepdf method.

The book is prepared so each tune appears chronologically, but it would be helpful to the user to have an alphabetical list of all the tunes and their page numbers near the front of the book.

It's easy to add a section for each PDF using the pagecommand={\section*{Section Name}} option, but it does not seem possible to sort a TOC alphabetically. All the responses to questions about sorting a TOC that I could find recommend that you use an index if you want an alphabetical list. However, pdfpages does not seem to allow for adding index entries and adding index entries either before or after \includepdf does not work.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Some time ago I showed how to add indexing to '\includepdf' here: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364832/80551>

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much.